# iOS CallKit, PushKit: Strange behaviour. Sometimes answering UI doesn't pop up

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I made an app for calls with CallKit and PushKit. It seems everything is done correctly, according to apples manual on  CallKit and PushKit. If I start app on two devices, and try to make a call everything is working for the first time, and it can work for the second time and so on. But then, by unknown reason (I don't handle any errors), the phone that receives voip push notification ringing but doesn't show the panel with answer/decline buttons. If that happens, new incoming calls work the same broken way.

To improve that broken situation I must initiate outgoing call with CallKit on broken phone.

I don't post any code, it just the same as in apples example or the same as [here](https://www.kodeco.com/1276414-callkit-tutorial-for-ios#toc-anchor-014).

Do anyone has guess what's wrong?

**EDIT:**

After some experiments I fond that this issue happens if I stop call on the device and then immediately initiate call on this device again. In case if I wait let say for 5 seconds between calls everything works as it should.

The question is still opened if code in examples and Apples manual is wrong, or it is an Apples bug.